# How to set high resolution images for iphone4 using css

Tags: iphone

In iphone4 images are not showing in high resolution its shows low resolution images.

How to change high resolution images for iphone4 using css?

---

To clarify, we are developing in phonegap using html and jquery  The high-res images end up pixelated in the application. The .png images have the designation of @2x.png and the raw files match the png files.

We have utilized the practices in
http://aralbalkan.com/3331
and
http://davidehlers.com/2011/03/iphone...

The images appear slightly smaller than the raw images are, and significantly pixelated. I have attached an overlay of the issue that Venky is referring to. This is the buttonsml@2x.png on the right, placed on top of the screenshot of the app from an iPhone4.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about CSS but in normal way you can append "@2x" to normal image name and that would be goes for Retina Display. So may be you don't need to mention that in CSS and just put @2x in image and add it in to the project. For example for icon.png it would be icon@2x.png.

Hope this help.

Comment: We tried image name as icon@2x.png. But it not changes to high resolution image

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten this to work by using the @2x versions in the image tags, and specifying a width/height that's half the size of the @2x image. For example, with a 200 x 80 "item@2x.png", I'd use:

```
<img src="item@2x.png" width="100" height="40">
```

It works well inside a UIWebView. Not sure about doing it with CSS though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use high resolution images.  The SDK will automatically select the high resolution version (@2x) if you load the image in code (UIImage imageNamed), but if you are doing through any other method you will have to do it yourself.

Comment: We tried image name as icon@2x.png. But it not changes to high resolution image